# Sort on a custom Linked List using c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have created a custom Linked List , code given below .
Now trying to implement a sort (its what I told to do, not the best choice I know) , how we can do in best possible time complexity or the best approach

my custom linked list
my doubt is over the last node , in each phase of bubble sort should try to sort last and then start over from first node , how to handle the last node as its points to the first node

```
    public class CustomCircularList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
    {

        Node<T> head = null;
        Node<T> tail = null;
        int count = 0;
        readonly IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;

        public int Count { get { return count; } }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            this.AddLast(item);
        }
         AddLast...
    }
}
```

my Node class has three properties

```
public T Value { get; private set; }
public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
public Node<T> Previous { get; set; }
```

I added IComparer to my class T like this and trying to work like below

```
 public class Fund: IComparer<Fund>
    {
        public string fundname{ get; set; }
        public int Compare([AllowNull] Fund x, [AllowNull] Fund y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return x.fundname.CompareTo(y.fundname);
      }
```

Comment: There is only a single possible complexity and approach given that *your specific requirements are to use a particular approach* that itself has a particular time complexity.  The way to have a better approach and/or a better time complexity is to *use a different approach, which violates your stated requirements*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me assume that `Node<T>` object has (at least) 2 standard properties: `Value` and `Next`:

```
public class Node<T> {
  ...
  public T Value {get; set;}
  public Node<T> Next {get;} 
}
```

Since you have *circular* linked list,

```
tail.Next == head
```

we can enumerate *all* items *except the last one* as

```
for (Node<T> node = head; !ReferenceEquals(node.Next, head); node = node.Next) {
  ...
}
```

Just for reference, should we have a linked list (*non circular*), the loop would be (all we should do is to change `head` to `null`):

```
for (Node<T> node = head; !ReferenceEquals(node.Next, null); node = node.Next) {
  ...
}
```

The code can be

```
public void BubbleSort(IComparer<T> comparer = null) {
  comparer ??= Comparer<T>.Default;

  if (comparer is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));

  if (head is null)
    return; // empty linked list

  bool agenda = true;

  while (agenda) {
    agenda = false;

    for (Node<T> node = head; !ReferenceEquals(node.Next, head); node = node.Next) 
      if (comparer.Compare(node.Value, node.Next.Value) > 0) {
        agenda = true;

        var help = node.Value; 
        node.Value = node.Next.Value;
        node.Next.Value = help;   
      } 
  } 
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to sort some custom type (`T`) you should either ensure the `T` implements `IComparable<T>`:

```
public class MyClass: IComparable<MyClass> {
  ...
  public int CompareTo(MyClass other) {
    TODO: return 0 if other == this, -1 if this < other, +1 if this > other
  }
}
```

or you should implement a *comparer* `IComparer<MyClass>` which you should provide as an argument:

```
public class MyComparer<MyClass> {
  public int Compare(MyClass x, MyClass y) {
    //TODO: return 0 when x == y, -1 when x < y, when x > y
  }
}
```

then

```
MyCircularLinkedList.BubbleSort(new MyComparer());
```

Comment: my Node class 3 properties , T Value , Next node and Previous Node, with this will your approach will be same

Comment: @mainak: I see, `Next` and `Value` are enough

Comment: how to use this bubblesort for a custom object or class

Comment: mainak: in case of custom class (`T`) if it doesn't implement `IComparable<T>` i.e. it doesn't provide some default algorithm how to compare its instances, you have to pass *comparer* as an argument.

Comment: can you give me any example link please

Comment: Suppose I have implemented IComparable<t> in my node class, then how to use this "BubbleSort "  method , like if you can give a code snippet

Comment: It is not `Node` but `T` should implement `Comparable<T>` - we compare `Value`s, not `Node<T>`s. If `T` is comparable, e.g. you have `Node<double>` and `T == double` is comparable, you don't have to implement anything

Comment: Hi @Dmitry -  I implemented IComparer<T> in my T class , but when I use bubble sort , its still giving me error like At least one object must implement IComparable.  I updated the question with code snippets , can you please suggest